# IOS Text filed word helper pop up view third part library

Tags: ios, user-interface, popup

1. I am implementing popup with word helper (I fetch array of word from
   my xml file) when user edit text in UITextField.
2. I can implement this using UITableView & also using third part
   library example
   http://code4app.net/ios/SGPopSelectView/54783371e24741234bb03ca0
3. My Query: IS their any good third party UI pop up library available to do so?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/50pixels/FPPopover looks better. The another one http://code4app.net/ios/ZSYPopoverListView/51aae6396803fa3e0f000002 also looks good but not perfect.